# Replace '\xa0' in string with spaces

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

My string is `'MRK\xa0Software\xa0Services\xa0Private\xa0Limited'`
and I want to replace the hexadecimal part (`\xa0`) with spaces, such that I get

`MRK Software Services Private Limited` which I can further split into different words.

Comment: Read about the `replace` method of `str` objects.

Comment: Why? '\xa0' is a non-break space. It looks like a space when you print it. It's used in multi-word names to stop them getting broken up by word-wrapping routines.

Comment: `\xa` is not [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)

Comment: @PM2Ring I wanted to split them into different words, but the split or replace part doesn't work. They show unicode error

Comment: If you want to split on that character, why not just do `test_string.split('\xa0')`?

Comment: @BenJones it shows an error - `(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-2: truncated \xXX escape`

Comment: Try `u'\xa0'`? And are you sure you put a `0` at the end?

Comment: @BenJones ahh, my fault. It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myString = "MRK\xa0Software\xa0Services\xa0Private\xa0Limited"

newString = myString.replace("\xa0", " ")
```

If you are getting unicode error you can try:

```
newString = myString.replace("\\xa0", " ")
```

Comment: `\xa0`, not `\xa`.

Comment: yeah you need to escape the \

Comment: Um, no, you should **not** escape the `\\`.

Comment: `myString.replace("\\xa0", " ")` would work if the input string was `r"MRK\xa0Software\xa0Services\xa0Private\xa0Limited"`. But it isn't.

Comment: Works either way for me?